# How to connect SQLite in excel web add-ins

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I am working on office add-ins using Vue JS. I want to connect SQLite local database.  I am using NodeJS for Backend. How to connect SQLite Database using VueJS

Comment: Office add-ins are web applications. You would connect to a backend SQLite DB the same way that you would in any web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework like [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize).

This is one example for Model:

db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');     
const sequelize = new Sequelize({           
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'database.sqlite'
  })
  
module.exports = sequelize;
```

model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('./db');


const Agendamento = database.define('agendamento', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    local: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    datainicio: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    datafim: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

module.exports = Agendamento;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I will let you know once done with implementation.